# Eventbrite API not returning Events

Tags: php, wordpress, eventbrite, genesis

So a site I am working on for a client, http://atasteofartistry.com, needs to have EventBrite integration. It is a wordpress install running a Genesis theme.

Right now, in functions.php, I have this:

```
//* EventBrite
require 'Eventbrite.php';

$eb_client = new Eventbrite( array('app_key'=>'(REDACTED)', 
                                   'user_key'=>'(REDACTED)'));

$arr = array('user'=>'atasteofartistry@gmail.com',
    'event_statuses'=>'live,started'
    );

e$events = $eb_client->user_list_events($arr);
```

and I have the call in a widget listed like this:

```
<h1>My Event List:</h1>
<?= Eventbrite::eventList( $events, 'eventListRow'); ?>  
</div>
```

On the site, I am not getting the events. The Eventbrite.php API client is initializing, because I get the "No Events" message, but I just cannot pass anything through to it.

I've been staring at it for 8 hours now and need help. So HELP!

I'm using the Eventbrite PHP library from Github.

https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php

How to fix it would be great, but I can't even figure out how to troubleshoot it.

Many thanks,

Joe

FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
<?php
//* Start the engine
include_once( get_template_directory() . '/lib/init.php' );

//* Setup Theme
include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lib/theme-defaults.php' );

//* EventBrite
require 'Eventbrite.php';

add_action( 'genesis_before', 'eventbrite_event_list');
function eventbrite_event_list() {

    $eb_client = new Eventbrite( array('app_key'=>'ECOC6TZS3JJVXLJ2MX', 
                                       'user_key'=>'1409014384112928178221'));

$arr = array('user'=>'atasteofartistry@gmail.com',
        'event_statuses'=>'live,started'
        );

   try {
        $events = $eb_client->user_list_events();
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        // Be sure to plan for potential error cases 
        // so that your application can respond appropriately

        //var_dump($e);
        $events = array();
    }

}

//* Set Localization (do not remove)
load_child_theme_textdomain( 'daily-dish', apply_filters( 'child_theme_textdomain', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages', 'daily-dish' ) );

//* Child theme (do not remove)
define( 'CHILD_THEME_NAME', __( 'Daily Dish Pro Theme', 'daily-dish' ) );
define( 'CHILD_THEME_URL', 'http://my.studiopress.com/themes/daily-dish/' );
define( 'CHILD_THEME_VERSION', '1.0' );

//* Enqueue scripts and styles
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'daily_dish_enqueue_scripts_styles' );
function daily_dish_enqueue_scripts_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'daily-dish-responsive-menu', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'daily-dish-google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900|Playfair+Display:400|Tangerine:400,700', array(), CHILD_THEME_VERSION );

}

add_filter( 'genesis_seo_title', 'custom_genesis_seo_title', 10, 1 );
/**
 * Replace Site Title text entered in Settings > Reading with custom HTML.
 * @author Sridhar Katakam
 * @link http://sridharkatakam.com/replace-site-title-text-custom-html-genesis/
 *
 * @param string original title text
 * @return string modified title HTML
 */
function custom_genesis_seo_title( $title ) {
    $title = '<h1 itemprop="headline" class="site-title"><a title="Homepage" href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '">a taste of <span class="artistry">ARTISTRY</span></a></h1>';
    return $title;
}

//* Add HTML5 markup structure
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list', 'gallery', 'caption', ) );

//* Add viewport meta tag for mobile browsers
add_theme_support( 'genesis-responsive-viewport' );

//* Add support for custom background
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array(
    'default-attachment' => 'fixed',
    'default-color'      => 'ffffff',
    'default-image'      => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/bg.png',
    'default-repeat'     => 'repeat',
    'default-position-x' => 'left',
) );

//* Add new image sizes
add_image_size( 'daily-dish-featured', 720, 470, TRUE );
add_image_size( 'daily-dish-archive', 340, 200, TRUE );
add_image_size( 'daily-dish-sidebar', 100, 100, TRUE );

//* Add support for custom header
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
    'header-selector' => '.site-title a',
    'header-text'     => false,
    'height'          => 80,
    'width'           => 400,
) );

/** Enable shortcodes to be used in widgets */
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

//* Unregister the header right widget area
unregister_sidebar( 'header-right' );

//* Remove navigation meta box
add_action( 'genesis_theme_settings_metaboxes', 'daily_dish_remove_genesis_metaboxes' );
function daily_dish_remove_genesis_metaboxes( $_genesis_theme_settings_pagehook ) {

    remove_meta_box( 'genesis-theme-settings-nav', $_genesis_theme_settings_pagehook, 'main' );

}

//* Remove output of primary navigation right extras
remove_filter( 'genesis_nav_items', 'genesis_nav_right', 10, 2 );
remove_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'genesis_nav_right', 10, 2 );

//* Reposition the secondary navigation menu
remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_subnav' );
add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'genesis_do_subnav' );

//* Hook before header widget area above header
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'daily_dish_before_header' );
function daily_dish_before_header() {

    genesis_widget_area( 'before-header', array(
        'before' => '<div class="before-header" class="widget-area"><div class="wrap">',
        'after'  => '</div></div>',
    ) );
}

add_theme_support( 'genesis-structural-wraps', array(
    'header',
    'nav',
    'subnav',
    'site-inner',
    'footer-widgets',
    'footer'
) );

//* Customize the entry meta in the entry header
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'daily_dish_single_post_info_filter' );
function daily_dish_single_post_info_filter( $post_info ) {

    $post_info = '[post_date] [post_author_posts_link] [post_comments] [post_edit]';
    return $post_info;

}

//* Customize the entry meta in the entry footer
add_filter( 'genesis_post_meta', 'daily_dish_post_meta_filter' );
function daily_dish_post_meta_filter($post_meta) {

    $post_meta = '[post_categories before=""] [post_tags before=""]';
    return $post_meta;

}

//* Remove comment form allowed tags
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'daily_dish_remove_comment_form_allowed_tags' );
function daily_dish_remove_comment_form_allowed_tags( $defaults ) {

    $defaults['comment_notes_after'] = '';
    return $defaults;

}

//* Walled Garden

// function walled_garden()
// {
// if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
// wp_redirect( '/wp-login.php' );
// }
// add_action( 'get_header', 'walled_garden' );

//* Add images to Site Header

add_action( 'genesis_site_title','add_header_images',8);
    function add_header_images() {

?>

<span><img src="../wp-content/themes/daily-dish-pro/images/wine-glass.png" class="header-glass" /></span>
<span><img src="../wp-content/themes/daily-dish-pro/images/splatter.png" class="splatter" /></span>

<?php

}

//* Modify the size of the Gravatar in the author box
add_filter( 'genesis_author_box_gravatar_size', 'daily_dish_author_box_gravatar' );
function daily_dish_author_box_gravatar( $size ) {

    return 180;

}

//* Modify the size of the Gravatar in the entry comments
add_filter( 'genesis_comment_list_args', 'daily_dish_comments_gravatar' );
function daily_dish_comments_gravatar( $args ) {

    $args['avatar_size'] = 96;

    return $args;

}

//* Hook before footer widget area below footer widgets
add_action( 'genesis_before_footer', 'daily_dish_before_footer_widgets', 5 );
function daily_dish_before_footer_widgets() {

    genesis_widget_area( 'before-footer-widgets', array(
        'before' => '<div class="before-footer-widgets" class="widget-area"><div class="wrap">',
        'after'  => '</div></div>',
    ) );

}

//* Hook after footer widget area below footer
add_action( 'genesis_after', 'daily_dish_after_footer' );
function daily_dish_after_footer() {

    genesis_widget_area( 'after-footer', array(
        'before' => '<div class="after-footer" class="widget-area"><div class="wrap">',
        'after'  => '</div></div>',
    ) );

}

//* Add support for 3-column footer widgets
add_theme_support( 'genesis-footer-widgets', 3 );

//* Add support for after entry widget
add_theme_support( 'genesis-after-entry-widget-area' );

//* Relocate after entry widget
remove_action( 'genesis_after_entry', 'genesis_after_entry_widget_area' );
add_action( 'genesis_after_entry', 'genesis_after_entry_widget_area', 5 );

//* Register widget areas
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'before-header',
    'name'        => __( 'Before Header', 'daily-dish' ),
    'description' => __( 'This is the before header widget area.', 'daily-dish' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'home-top',
    'name'        => __( 'Home - Top', 'daily-dish' ),
    'description' => __( 'This is the top section of the homepage.', 'daily-dish' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'home-middle',
    'name'        => __( 'Home - Middle', 'daily-dish' ),
    'description' => __( 'This is the middle section of the homepage.', 'daily-dish' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'home-bottom',
    'name'        => __( 'Home - Bottom', 'daily-dish' ),
    'description' => __( 'This is the bottom section of the homepage.', 'daily-dish' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'before-footer-widgets',
    'name'        => __( 'Before Footer Widgets', 'daily-dish' ),
    'description' => __( 'This is the before footer widgets section.', 'daily-dish' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'after-footer',
    'name'        => __( 'After Footer', 'daily-dish' ),
    'description' => __( 'This is the after footer section.', 'daily-dish' ),
) );
```

Comment: Does anything get written into the logs?

Comment: Which logs? The WP logs?

Comment: I was wrong, no current errors.

Comment: You have a syntax error, according to the log. If you can put your entire functions.php file in a gist, I can at least figure out where that syntax error is.

Comment: That was an old error. My UTC wasn't set so that threw me off. Does the "$eb_client..." belong in the body?

Comment: I put it there anyway, but I dont think the problem is there